# update all R packages after changing R version from 3.3.0 to 3.5.0

Tags: r, r-package

I want to modify the R version and associated R packages in a docker image. The docker image was built in Debian GNU/Linux 8 (Jessie) and had R 3.3.0. R packages were configured with `make install`. I updated the R to 3.5.0 and wanted to update other packages too but ran into version incompatibility issues with many packages. Here is one example:

`Error : package 'stringi' was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version`

Is there any way to update all R packages after R version changed from 3.3.0 to 3.5.0?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52010147/9406040) to `r update.packages() not updating packages that are imported by other packages`

Comment: Why did you only update to 3.5? The current version of R is 4.1.2. You can't really "update" packages between major versions, you just need to reinstall. They go to a different library path by default on most systems.

Comment: @MrFlick Wait, what? R doesn't update to the highest (possible) version of a package via `utils::update.packages()`?

Comment: @Roman. update.packages() does not update to the highest possible version. CRAN doesn't really keep track of that. I can only try to update to the current CRAN release version. And the current version of many packages probably wont support older versions all the way back to 3.5. When you install a newer version of R (where the first or second version number changes), the library should be empty by default. There should be nothing to update unless you manually try to move things over or manipulate your library paths.

Comment: You could make a copy of the packages in the older version and then pass the vector to `install.packages()`. Check [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/upgrade-r-without-losing-your-packages/)